# jquery, Slider only goes round once

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, intervals

I have this, which is an image slider thats meant to keep going round once it gets to the end and back:

```
 $(function () {
    var sliderUL = $('div.headslide').children('ul'),
    imgs = sliderUL.find('img'),
    imgWidth = imgs[0].width,
    imgsLenth = imgs.length,
    current = 1,
    totalImgsWidth = imgsLenth * imgWidth,
    direction = 'next',
    loc = imgWidth,
    interval = setInterval(swapBKgnd, 9000);

function swapBKgnd() {

    (direction === 'next') ? ++current : --current;

    if (current === 0) {
        current = imgsLenth;
        loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth;
        direction = 'next';
    } else if (current - 1 === imgsLenth) {
        current = 1;
        loc = 0;
    }


    transition(sliderUL, loc, direction);
};

function transition(container, loc, direction) {
    var unit;

    if (direction && loc !== 0 ) {
        unit = (direction === 'next') ? '-=' : '+=';
    }

    container.animate({
        'margin-left': unit ? (unit + loc) : loc,
    });
}
});
```

It's meant to keep going but once it gets to the end and back to the first... It stops. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reach the end of your images, you set `loc = 0` and then `current = 1`.  However, on the next iteration, `loc` is still `0`, so it doesn't move.  You need to add an `else`:

```
if (current === 0) {
    current = imgsLenth;
    loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth;
    direction = 'next';
} else if (current - 1 === imgsLenth) {
    current = 1;
    loc = 0;
} else {
    loc = imgWidth;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/5W8Av/

Comment: Thanks, Really not with it today.. Also, You wouldn't happen to know why this will not work in chrome atall? http://fear.kennyist.com/

Comment: @Kennyist: WebKit browsers behave differently with `img.width`, due to the way they load images.  There are some ways to get this to behave correctly, but in your case it might be easier to set `imgWidth` to a static value of `1000`.  This is the easiest fix, and if your headers are always the same size, it should work fine.

Comment: @Kennyist:  I reread my comment and realized I wasn't very clear.  Your problem is caused by `img.width` returning `0` in Chrome.  Like I said above, there are solutions to this, but you might be better off using a constant value for the width.